# Static properties in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create a service in Polymer but I don't understand how I'm supposed to create static properties.

I would need them to share the same value for all instances ("static") BUT I would also need the observers to be triggered on every instance when they are updated.

I know I could create a variable in the scope of the Polymer() call like this :

```
var users = [];
Polymer({
  is: 'my-service',
  properties: {
    users: {
      type: Array,
      value: users,
      notify: true,
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

But it doesn't meet the second criteria. If I update it from one instance, it doesn't trigger the observers of the other instances.

Do you know how to perform that without triggering the observers on each instance manually ? (I could do it but it would defeat the idea of using a framework in this case.)

EDIT: An alternative would be to create a singleton, but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite simple to create static properties with observers. The issue that you are running into is a combination of the design of Polymer and the native implementation of Array.prototype methods.

Arrays and Object observers (deep/path observers) work a little differently than other property observers. In general, notify will only work when the *instance* changes. Additionally, most Array.prototype.functions return a new instance of the modified array... So, when you splice the array, a different instance is set into the object's property value *(not the static property's value)* and is now no longer equal to the original static array that you set. This is why only the modifying instance is notified.

My only recommendation to overcome this is: Don't use `Array.prototype.splice()`, or `this.splice()`. Even if you do this upon the static property, the result will always be a new array causing incongruous data. From here, you have two options: use Polymer's `set` API or delete the index and manually `notifyPath()`

Here is the link that discusses both:

[Data binding - Path change notification](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path)

Comment: I don't understand the part where you say that a new array is created with splice(). From what I've seen, there is no new array (no new reference/instance) and both the property in the instance of MyService and the variable accessible by closure change (as they are the same array). The property on other instances also changes, but they're not notified. I understand this behavior and find it logical, but to create a fully functional static property, I need all instances of MyService to be notified. The fact that splice() doesn't create a new array also prevents notifyPath() to work.

Comment: I know this is years old, but some logics just don't change. Looking into Polymer 3 (which is at this time early beta), and was trying to understand the logic in making a static getter for attribute properties, and this made everything clear. Thank you Fuzzical Logic. (Your name is somewhat ironic in this instance... ;) )

Answer (score 1):

```
<dom-module id="my-service">
  <template>
    <iron-meta id="my-service-users" value="{{users}}"></iron-meta>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-service',
      properties: {
        users: {
          type: Array,
          value: function(){return [];},
          notify: true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`iron-meta` creates a singleton value that automatically updates the `users` value in all instances, which should also trigger any relevant observers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this workaround and even added the key attribute but the observer (`usersChanged(users, users.splices)`) was only triggered for the instance that made the modification. It seems the meta value (obtained using the `byKey(...)` function of the iron-meta component) isn't updated despite the fact that the `value` attribute on the same iron-meta component is correctly updated. Am I missing something ?